# github Repository not found using ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh

I know there are multiple questions about this online but nothing solved it so far...

first I created a new github account and added a new repository.
Then I created a node-react project locally and initialized the main branch and added the newly created remote with the ssh url.

```
git init -b main

git add .

git commit -m "initial commit"

git remote add origin <ssh-remote-url>
```

Then I [created a new ssh key locally](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#generating-a-new-ssh-key) and added it to the ssh-agent.
like described in the github [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#generating-a-new-ssh-key)

I also added the key to my new github account. As described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)
The key on Github is the same key like the one in my ssh-agent I checked several times using

```
ssh-add -l
```

Then I tried to push

```
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

and got this here

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have my own github email and name set to the global git conf.
So I added the email and name of the new created account to the local .git/config.
using

```
git config user.email example@email.com
git config user.name examplename
```

still no luck. Ok I then invited myselfe to the repository as a collaborator
and added my name and email to .git/config of the local repository.

Tried to push again with the same error.

I also removed the old key, created a new one and added it to github. I removed the .git folder and initialized git again locally. I also created another repo trying to push to another repo with no luck.

I was so desperat, I even tried adding the https url as the remote origin, also no luck...

any tips here am I missing somethink?

Comment: test `ssh -T git@github.com` and see what that gives you.  If you get an authentication error, you set up your key incorrectly on github.    If you get your github name back, you set up your key correctly and your origin is set up incorrectly.

Comment: oh, I see the username of a different ssh-key. (I have 2 ssh-keys in my ssh-agent)
I think I need to manage multible accounts, wasn't aware... I will look into that!

Comment: ssh-agent can try a number of keys (at least 5).  But the first key that is recognized by github will authenticate you as that user.  So you can't use the same `ssh-agent` by 2 different github users at the same time.  you can start a new agent, or look into a method such as this one: https://gist.github.com/yinzara/bbedc35798df0495a4fdd27857bca2c1